# numpy array with dtype as str can't sum with itself?

Tags: python, numpy

If I do

```py
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 'A', 'B'], dtype=str)
print(l + l)
```

I get the error "numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U3'), dtype('<U3')) -> dtype('<U3')"

I don't understand why something like this would happen, l surely has the same dtype as itself. If I also create a new array and try to add them both, this error will still occur, even after converting both dtypes to str.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: It's telling you **it doesn't support the unicode dtype for that operation**.

Comment: The error isn't complaining about different dtypes.  It's a question of what does `+` mean when dealing with strings.  Python strings defines it as join.  `+` for numeric dtypes is addition. The `numpy` developers chose not to define it for string dtypes.  For the most part, `numpy` does not have any fast compiled code for strings; the `np.char` functions all use Python's own string methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specified `str` type, I assume that the `+` operation you want is string concatenation.  NumPy does not inherently map `+` to its broadcast operations in this context.  Instead, use the [documented operation `char.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html#module-numpy.char):

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 'A', 'B'], dtype=str)

print(l)
print(l[0] + l[1])
print(np.char.add(l, l))
```

Output:

```
['1' '2' '3' 'A' 'B']
12
['11' '22' '33' 'AA' 'BB']
```